# Retrieve PFObject from Parse. Not by objectId

Tags: ios, object, parse-platform

I have a table called "UserSnapshot" on Parse and of course you get the objectID's as you populate the table.

However, when I query the table for an object from my app I wont have the object ID's but I will have their "UserCode". I have been playing with something like this.

```
    PFQuery *userProfile = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserSnapshot"];
[userProfile whereKey:@"Code" equalTo:_Code];
[userProfile getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        // Did not find PFObject
        // not executed
    } else {
        // Found PFObject
        // also not executed....huh?
    }
}];
```

But nothing happens. Neither the if or the else is entered. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Is there at least one object for it to actually find?  Otherwise you should use findObjectsInBackground.

Comment: Doesn't work either :( Seems to hit the line then complete skip over as if its failed. Not failed to get objects but failed failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    PFQuery *userProfile = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserSnapshot"];
[userProfile whereKey:@"Code" equalTo:_Code];
PFObject *object = [userProfile getFirstObject];
```

Works!

Comment: That's good to know, but it's not good to execute network calls on the main thread. Hopefully you can find out why the background calls aren't working.

Comment: To be honest once I have the info I will be saving to disk so at this point I don't think I mind so much. But you're right, I really want to know what I was going wrong. It'll bug me like a seeing an actor you know but who's name you can't think of.

Comment: You may also try dispatching a background thread and just executing the `[userProfile getFirstObject]` in the block of the background thread. That may work.

Comment: socaljoker that is exactly what I ended up doing! If you write the answer up I will mark you as correct as technically it's the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything print out in the log/console? It's possible that you didn't set your keys properly when initializing Parse in your App Delegate.

Comment: My keys are set, my app is uploading data at least. I am on the right track right? I mean I know a certain col in my table is unique. So getfirstObjectinBackgroundWithBlock with my query set that way should just give me the PFObject, right?

Comment: It should. You're sure that the query is getting executed, right? If so, it should be calling the completion block when it finishes, whether it was successful or not. If you print out the value of `error`, does it print anything?

Comment: That's just the thing, it doesn't enter the if or the else. It's almost as if it hits the line and skips it. Of course error is then out of scope.

Comment: Try using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead of `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:`.

Comment: Have. In debug when you step over it honestly just skips right past everything as if it gets to the line and just ignores it and moves on skipping over everything. So bizarre.

Comment: ViewDidLoad. The view is of course just looking to find 1 user in my database but not by the given objectID of Parse but by a value in the object I know to be unique. I was calling the getfirstobject out of safety.